# Nginx 301 redirect old domain to the single homepage on a new domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect multiple URL on the old domain to the single page on the new one.

```
old-domain.com/one
old-domain.com/query?=two
old-domain.com/one/cat+mouse
```

Should all redirect to `new-domain.com/`

Using the following, it redirects the whole path, not to the homepage:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old-domain.com;
  return 301 http://new-domain.com;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to redirect only the domain, you'll need

```
return 301 $scheme://new-domain.com$request_uri;
```

If you need to redirect everything to the new home, try

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    return 301 $scheme://new-domain.com/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here at [Directory 301 Redirect](http://atulhost.com/301-redirect-in-nginx). It might be easier to use the nginx rewrite module. I would try something like this...

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old-domain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://new-domain.com permanent;
}
```